# How to open pdf from url in webview that's not ends with ".pdf"?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, android-webview, google-document-viewer

I searched how to open pdf document in webview. I can open any url that ends withs '.pdf' but I need open a url that's not ends with '.pdf'. I can not solve this.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreateFinished() {
    binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.displayZoomControls = true
    val url = "urlEndsWithout.pdf"
    val googleDocsUrl = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url
    binding.webView.loadUrl(googleDocsUrl)
}
```

That is error I get it:
"Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'require-trusted-types-for'.
", source: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.lb.en.S9zOXUg9rrA.O%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAHpOoo-AXjUK4hNAaKzui0P9Fr9nG2_yZQ%2Fm%3D__features__#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com&rpctoken=887135553

Comment: In what do you want to open that pdf? Who should display it?

Comment: `"urlEndsWithout.pdf"` We dont see that in the error message.

Comment: Download the PDF, then open it in the user's preferred PDF viewer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I must display it on webview.

Comment: @blackapps it's a url. I did not paste here url. But I its not ends with .pdf so that make problem to display. How can achieve this I don't know.

Comment: Then use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Comment: @CommonsWare How can use this? It's not android library?

Comment: Correct. It is JavaScript and HTML, designed to be used in a Web browser. That would include a `WebView`. You could host it on the server that contains the PDF and set up the HTML to load that PDF. Or, you could include it as assets in your Android app, with modifications to allow it to load PDFs from arbitrary sources. I did this several years ago and covered the process in the "Viewing PDFs" chapter of [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android).

Comment: Thank you for the book. I don't access server. I will want them add .pdf to path or will use intent outside app.